# How do I insert a custom HTML file into WordPress without affecting the theme or other parts of the site

Tags: wordpress

I am in the process of setting up a website with another author and want to have a stand alone front page which is a different theme from the rest of the site. Basically he has made the front page in an editor and sent me the file which is linked below. I have made the rest of the website and I just want to insert his front page in.

I have tried just pasting the HTML code into the page under code editor but it is formatted horribly and does not show up the same as when I click on the link.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4GBP5O9HNGN

This is the page I want as the homepage

Comment: This question has been answered very thoroughly on the WP Stack site - [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296592/how-to-use-custom-html-file-instead-of-wordpress-homepage](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296592/how-to-use-custom-html-file-instead-of-wordpress-homepage)

Answer (score 0):

To add your front page to theme, create a child folder of the theme and create a page template on child theme. Then create a new page from dashboard and select the created page template then go to settings>>readings and check static homepage and select your page.
I hope this works let me know if this works.